# Use of data-toggle="tooltip" in <a> or <span>

Tags: javascript, html, css, tooltip

when I use `data-toggle="tooltip"` with the tag `<h>`, it works normally:

```
    <h3 data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" 
    title="example"> example </h3>
```

but when I try to use with `<a>/<td>/<span>`, this does not work normally, it just shows the normal tool-tip, without any style.

I'm starting with JavaScript and CSS, so I'm a bit stuck.

What can I do to solve this?

(I'm aware there are similar questions to this but they haven't solved my problem)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is meant by `with //,`

Comment: When an element does not inherit the styles you expect it to, it's usually because those styles haven't been declared to that element. Check your selectors, for example, your tooltip styles could only be applied to `h3` elements.

Comment: Can you share your work so far? I want to see where you are stuck. Because I am not getting in which context you are asking. Are you using bootstrap tooltip or you have created your own using javascript and style is not reflecting.  From your line of `h3` code  I think its bootstrap but still want to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/fgcb27aa/

Check if you have tooltips enabled in your current page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

Comment: @AntonioSerrano can you show some of your code or even a jsfiddle with an example of what's not working? It's harder to figure out the issue without any context